# Which collection(s) to store groups of users?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I want to make a collection that stores groups of users. A user can be a member of multiple groups, groups can be nested, a selection of groups should return a distinct IEnumerable`<user`> .

I could write this from scratch of course using the standard List`<T`>,Dictionary<`T,`U> etc collections, but is there a built-in collection that already exposes a lot of this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User>
        {
            // use a List<T> to hold the users themselves
        };
    }
}

class Group
{
    public Group NestedGroup { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    // Store the groups in a HashSet<T> to keep
    // a distinct list.
    HashSet<Group> groups;

    public IEnumerable<Group> Groups
    {
        get { return groups; }
    }
}
```

Using a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to hold the users themselves should be fine.  Notice that the `Groups` property of the `User` type is exposed as an `IEnumerable<Group>` but is implemented internally as a [`HashSet<Group>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) to allow you to keep a distinct list as you wanted.

Comment: The hashset was useful. It turned out that I did not need nested groups after all. Just categories that could be unioned or intersected. The hashset takes care of that the union or intersection operations will return a IEnumerable of distinct users.
I did not like the notion that a User should know about to which categories it belongs, so I did not implement is.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a thought a generic `List<T>` would work (where T is the class that holds your user).

Comment: I think he needs a bit more functionality that what is provided by the basic List

Comment: I would have thought the List<T> would hold users and the User class would expose a property that is a Dictionary or HashSet of Groups? Doesn't seem like anything out of ordinary? (But I may be missing something - I often do!)

Comment: I may just have misread the question, upon rereading (again) I am still uncertain what part of the functionality described is being taken care of in the user class, and what is being handled by the data-structures

Answer (score 0):

I would think that using `List<T>` would work for saving this information.  You could have Groups with a parent group and a list of children groups, and each group containing a list of members, or something similar.

In terms of getting the `IEnumerable<User>` back out - this should be doable using [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549142.aspx).  Take a look at the MSDN sample there - they have a similar thing with pets and owners, where there are multiple elements spanning multiple collections.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a good old relational database.  Throw in SQLite and go if you can.

Otherwise...I've sometimes done this via multiple Dictionaries and lists.  You have a Dictionary of Groups, each group is a list.  Then another Dictionary to store the users by a key of some sorts.  Each user can exists in multiple groups that way.